# actionscript arrays merge

Tags: actionscript-3, merge, arrays

I posted my problem a few hours ago, but I think I figured out how to ask my question in a more comprehensible way.

This is my code:

```
// 1. Intro
var introPL1:Array = ["intro1","intro2","intro3","intro4"];
var introPL2:Array = ["intro5","intro6","intro7","intro8","intro9"];
var introPL3:Array = ["intro10","intro11"];
var introPL4:Array = ["intro12","intro13"];
var allIntro:Array = [introPL1,introPL2,introPL3,introPL4];
// 2. Clothes
var clothesPL1:Array = ["clothes1","clothes2","clothes3","clothes4","clothes5"];
var clothesPL2:Array = ["clothes6","clothes7","clothes8"];
var clothesPL3:Array = ["clothes9","clothes10"];
var clothesPL4:Array = ["clothes11","clothes12","clothes13"];
var allClothes:Array = [clothesPL1,clothesPL2,clothesPL3,clothesPL4];
// 3. Colored Numbers
var colNumPL1:Array = ["colNum1","colNum2","colNum3","colNum4","colNum5"];
var colNumPL2:Array = ["colNum6","colNum7","colNum8"];
var colNumPL3:Array = ["colNum9","colNum10"];
var colNumPL4:Array = ["colNum11","colNum12","colNum13"];
var allColNum:Array = [colNumPL1,colNumPL2,colNumPL3,colNumPL4];

var allStuff:Array;
allStuff = allIntro.concat(allClothes, allColNum);
trace(allStuff[4]);
```

When I trace allStuff[4] it displays "clothes1,clothes2,clothes3,clothes4,clothes5".
The thing is, I would like all the stuff to be in the allStuff array (without sub-arrays) and when I trace allStuff[4], I would like it to display "intro5" (the fifth item in the huge allStuff array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function you want to use then is `concat`

here's the example from [adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#concat%28%29)

```
var numbers:Array = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var letters:Array = new Array("a", "b", "c");
var numbersAndLetters:Array = numbers.concat(letters);
var lettersAndNumbers:Array = letters.concat(numbers);

trace(numbers);       // 1,2,3
trace(letters);       // a,b,c
trace(numbersAndLetters); // 1,2,3,a,b,c
trace(lettersAndNumbers); // a,b,c,1,2,3
```

---

it's pretty straight forward:

```
allStuff= allStuff.concat(introPL1,introPL2,introPL3,introPL4,clothesPL1,clothesPL2,clothesPL3,clothesPL4,colNumPL1,colNumPL2,colNumPL3,colNumPL4);
```

you could also do a

```
allStuff = []
for each(var $string:String in $arr){
   allStuff.push($string)
}
```

for each array, or make it into a function

Comment: this doesn't help me at all, bro. I have already checked out the "help" from adobe. and it sux. could you please help me using an example from the code I provided here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, once you have declared your arrays like so, you need an additional operation to flatten your arrays `allClothes` and so on. Do like this:

```
function flatten(a:Array):Array {
    // returns an array that contains all the elements 
    // of parameter as a single array
    var b:Array=[];
    for (var i:int=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if (a[i] is Array) b=b.concat(flatten(a[i]));
        else b.push(a[i]);
    }
    return b;
}
```

What does it do: The function makes an empty array first, then checks the parameter member by member, if the i'th member is an Array, it calls itself with that member as a parameter, and adds the result to its temporary array, otherwise it's just pushing next member of `a` into the temporary array. So, to make your `allIntro` a flat array, you call `allIntro=flatten(allIntro)` after declaring it as you did. The same for other arrays.

Comment: hi Vesper - I don't know why but when I do this what you've suggested here, when I trace the array.length  - my arrays are always one item longer (a phantom item perhaps) than they should be.

Comment: If you trace the arrays themselves, where is the "phantom item" located? There should be none, but if the source array had a null item, then it'll remain in the result. Check inputs please.

Comment: I tried to search for it - couldn't find it. To be honest I'm an AS3 beginner and reading the code someone else writes is a bit of an enigma cracking for me. So I found another solution and now it (somehow) works just right :) Thanks for the help anyway.